# ToggleButton is always true MVVM WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a little problem. I have 3 states for a togglebutton - two checked and one unchecked, but it is always checked. I don't know why.

XAML:

```
<ToggleButton Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Style="{DynamicResource MetroCircleToggleButtonStyle}" IsChecked="{Binding Path=RepeatChecked}" Command="{Binding Path=RepeatCommand}">
            <Image Source="../Ressources/repeat.png"></Image>
</ToggleButton>
```

C#:

```
private void RepeatFunction()
        {
            if (!this.RepeatChecked)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Not checked");
                this.RepeatChecked = true;
                this.stateRepeat = StateRepeat.ONE;
            }
            else if (this.RepeatChecked && this.stateRepeat == StateRepeat.ONE)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Not checked - 2");
                this.RepeatChecked = true;
                this.stateRepeat = StateRepeat.ALL;
            }
            else if (this.RepeatChecked)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Checked");
                this.RepeatChecked = false;
                this.stateRepeat = StateRepeat.NONE;
            }
        }
```

The console write is always Checked. I really don't understand.

EDIT:

```
this.stateRepeat = StateRepear.NONE;
this.RepeatCommand = new CommandProvider(obj => RepeatFunction());
```

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint in `RepeatFunction` and stepped through the code?

Comment: No but when i click on it, that juste write "Checked"

Comment: You need to step through and see what values your variables **actually** have.

Comment: Please, also, show RepeatChecked property realization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that on click of toggle button, you always set the `RepeatChecked` to false/true which is bind to `IsChecked` which updates toggle state sets unchecked/checked again; so checked changes to unchecked and unchecked changes to check. Comment the line in all three conditions and run the flow and you will see all conditions working.

```
private void RepeatFunction()
{
    if (!this.RepeatChecked)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Not checked");
        ////this.RepeatChecked = true;
        this.stateRepeat = StateRepeat.ONE;
    }
    else if (this.RepeatChecked && this.stateRepeat == StateRepeat.ONE)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Not checked - 2");
        ////this.RepeatChecked = true;
        this.stateRepeat = StateRepeat.ALL;
    }
    else if (this.RepeatChecked)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Checked");
        ////this.RepeatChecked = false;
        this.stateRepeat = StateRepeat.NONE;
    }
}
```